# License Plate Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

> A license-plate number consists of $3$ letters followed by $4$ digits. What is the probability of choosing a plate that has neither a zero nor 'O'?

My try

All possible plates= $ 26^3×10^4$

Number of $4$-digit numbers with no "$0$"=$9^4$

Number  of $3$-letter Words with no "O"= $25^3$

## Required probability =$ \frac {9^4×25^3}{26^3×10^4}$

Is that right?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Indeed it is.  Nice work.

Comment: looks right to me

Comment: @N. F. Taussig thank you sir for  your kindness

Comment: Maybe a clearer way to write the answer is $\left(\frac{25}{26}\right)^3\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^4.$